# Android Realm updateRealmResults() not working

Tags: android, realm

What is the general procedure to doing search and updating RealmBaseAdapter with updated list of search results?

I have got the following code:

```
public void searchVideos(String searchText)
{
    RealmResults<TutorialModel> results = realm.where(TutorialModel.class).contains("title",
            searchText, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();

    videoListAdapter.updateRealmResults(results);
    videoListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

But my list of cell isn't updating to show the search results.

I am using RealmBaseAdapter and GridView. My `videoListAdapter` extends `RealmBaseAdapter`.

Am I doing something wrong?

The documentation here:

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Does not even contain a single word matching "updateRealmResults".

I'm hoping I don't have to resort to:

```
RealmResults<TutorialModel> results = realm.where(TutorialModel.class).contains("title",
                searchText, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();

videoListAdapter = new VideoListAdapter(this, results, true);

tblVideos.setAdapter(videoListAdapter);
```

That would suck if I have to.

Please tell me there is a more proper way...

### Update

I've also tried:

```
realm.beginTransaction();
arrItems.clear();
realm.commitTransaction();

RealmResults<TutorialModel> results = realm.where(TutorialModel.class).contains("title",
            searchText, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();

videoListAdapter.updateRealmResults(results);
videoListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

However, it appears somehow Realm results are linked, meaning if I went `arrItems.clear()` it clears those result from all search query...a pain in the butt...causing any subsequent RealmResults to return 0 results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised my mistake.

My `VideoListAdapter` originally was a `BaseAdapter`, and so I was using a variable called `arrItems` in my BaseAdapter.

Ever since changing my VideoListAdapter class to `RealmBaseAdapter`, I hadn't realised I also need to change the adapter to use realm's already defined `this.realmResults`

So I had something like this before:

```
public VideoListAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<TutorialModel> realmResults, boolean
        automaticUpdate)
{
    super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate);

    this.context = context;
    this.arrItems = realmResults;
}
```

When it should have been:

```
public VideoListAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<TutorialModel> realmResults, boolean
        automaticUpdate)
{
    super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate);

    this.context = context;
    this.realmResults = realmResults;
}
```

And use `this.realmResults` in place where I had use `this.arrItems` through the adapter delegate methods such as `getItemCount()`, `getView()` etc.

:D

New code in my Activity update to:

```
public void searchVideos(String searchText)
{
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    // note: this arrItems is my Activity's arrItems, 
    // not the adapter's this.realmResults
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    arrItems = realm.where(TutorialModel.class).contains("title",
            searchText, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();

    videoListAdapter.updateRealmResults(arrItems);
}
```

I'm one happy chap again.